# How can i rearrange my columns in the results? MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, workbench

Newbie here.

I used the following code to get the results for total number of users per month per year.

```
select 
    count(*) as 'new users',
    year(joined_at) as year, 
    month(joined_at) as month 
from users
group by year, month
order by year asc, month asc;
```

The results are shown in a table in the order of

```
 new users | year | month
```

How can I get the results to show as

```
Year | Month | New users
```

Comment: just change the order of the columns in `SELECT`. `SELECT first_visible_column, second_visible_column, third_visible_column FROM table_name`

Answer (score 1):

This query would produce the result you require, Year | Month |New users.

All you needed to do was rearrange your columns in your select statement. They appear in the order you add them to the query.

```
select 
 year(joined_at) as year, 
 month(joined_at) as month,
 count(*) as 'new users'
from users
group by year, month
order by year asc, month asc;
```